# Method that generate events in Json not running (Python)

Tags: python, sql, events

Hi there I have this python script below from a programming course to generate Json files (dictionaries) from events (concerts, shows, theatres) and can simulate a ticketing website with some additional info to keep track on the number of views, likes and clicks for each as customers interface with it over time. As an example please see the payload below that should be generated from this script:

```
    {
      "id": "5ee31063-e107-404c-8e7c-e4f1e09ea449",
      "ip": "21.33.54.112",
      "source": "android",
      "user_id": "3cc6870b-9f59-4e29-ab3a-ce2052d992db",
      "properties": {
        "type": "event_shared",
        "recieved_at": "2023-01-01T03:06:30",
        "event_name": "Fred Again: O2 Academy Brixton"
      }
    }
```

The issue is that whenever I try to run this it keeps saying the "click" module has not been found whenever I run the script "generate.py" below. I am trying to run with CMD the command "py -m generate --day 2023-01-01" but keep getting the "No module named "click" ". I was not sure I would need the "click" file placed somewhere as the zip file I received from my teacher has no reference to any "click" method. Any suggestions as to how I should create this "click" file / method? Also do I need a requirement file and place in there the version for the "click" method?

---

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import random
from datetime import datetime, date
from uuid import uuid4
import json
from pathlib import Path
import os
import shutil
import click


ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DATA_OUT_PATH = f"{ROOT_DIR}/data"

TRACKING_SOURCES = {"android", "web", "ios"}
SESSION_PROPERTY_VALUES = {
    "event_viewed",
    "event_liked",
    "event_shared",
    "event_disliked",
}
EVENT_NAMES = {
    "U2: Brixton",
    "Shakira: Los Angeles",
    "Coldplay: Bristol",
}


@dataclass
class SessionProperties:
    type: str
    recieved_at: str
    event_name: str


@dataclass
class Session:
    id: str
    ip: str
    source: str
    user_id: int
    properties: SessionProperties


def random_ip() -> list[str]:
    return ".".join([str(random.randint(0, 255)) for _ in range(4)])


def random_source() -> str:
    return random.choice(list(TRACKING_SOURCES))


def random_event_property_type() -> str:
    return random.choice(list(SESSION_PROPERTY_VALUES))


def random_id() -> str:
    return str(uuid4())


def random_event() -> str:
    return random.choice(list(EVENT_NAMES))


def random_session_properties(recieved_at: datetime) -> SessionProperties:
    return SessionProperties(
        type=random_event_property_type(),
        recieved_at=recieved_at.isoformat(),
        event_name=random_event(),
    )


def write_nd_out(file_name: str, data: list[Session]) -> None:
    p = Path(os.path.dirname(file_name))
    os.makedirs(p, exist_ok=True)
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        for session in data:
            f.write(json.dumps(session))
            f.write("\n")


def generate_hour(day_to_generate: date, hour: int, hourly_path: str):
    shutil.rmtree(hourly_path, ignore_errors=True)
    random_number_of_files = random.randint(1, 10)
    for _ in range(random_number_of_files):
        random_number_of_sessions = random.randint(1, 100)
        sessions = []
        for _ in range(random_number_of_sessions):
            random_session = Session(
                id=random_id(),
                ip=random_ip(),
                source=random_source(),
                user_id=random_id(),
                properties=random_session_properties(
                    datetime(
                        day_to_generate.year,
                        day_to_generate.month,
                        day_to_generate.day,
                        hour,
                        random.randint(0, 59),
                        random.randint(0, 59),
                    )
                ),
            )
            sessions.append(asdict(random_session))
        write_nd_out(f"{hourly_path}/{random_id()}.json", sessions)


def _root_path(day_to_generate: date) -> str:
    return f"{DATA_OUT_PATH}/{day_to_generate.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}"

@click.command()
@click.option('--day', type=click.DateTime(formats=["%Y-%m-%d"]),
              default=str(date.today()))
def main(day: datetime):
    for hour in range(0, 24):
        hourly_path = f"{_root_path(day.date())}/{hour:02}"
        generate_hour(day.date(), hour, hourly_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Use `pip install click`

Comment: @Barmar Brilliant, thank you! How did you know I had to run pip for this one? Is click widely used out there? :)

Comment: That's the general tool for installing third-party libraries in python.

Comment: Sure, but how did you know it was a third party library as opposed to one to be built by yourself?

Comment: Because `click` is a well-known library.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/click/